# Communicating by JSON Rest Server (Jersey) and Android

Tags: java, android, rest, jersey, gson

I am trying to do a simple application where I have:

(Server)
- Jersey RESTful

(Client)
- Android

I am trying to make them to communicate via JSON, I have seen several materials, but I still couldn't do it.

Follow my codes. If someone can help me. I am very pleased

Server Code:

```
  @POST
  @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
  @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
  public void consomeJson(Gson json) {
      System.out.println(json);
  }
```

Client code:

```
public void onBtnSalvarClicked(View view)
{        
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    TextView nome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
    TextView login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLogin);
    TextView senha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSenha);

    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    usuario.setNome(nome.getText().toString());
    usuario.setLogin(login.getText().toString());
    usuario.setSenha(senha.getText().toString());

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    params.put("var", gson.toJson(usuario));

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.2:8080/rest/hello");

    try{
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(gson.toString());
        httppost.setEntity(se);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are making an HTTP request on the UI thread, which Android isn't going to like. You should at least use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). More info [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) on network operations.

Also, make sure you are including the network permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Check out Android's new Volley library as well. It is supposed to make network requests much simpler. There's a tutorial [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library) and some more info in [the Google IO talk](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728).